# rails jquery cannot detect ajax event while event actually triggered

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to bind an ajax response from my rails server; however, in my jquery code, I cannot detect any of the ajax event, even though I know that the event have in fact triggered, since I'm getting the correct response from my server.

The reason I know the event have triggered, is because when I click on the submit button on the form, I receive a response from the server(I see the response in network tab in Chrome Developer Tool); and the response body contains the hash data that I coded in there to send back to my browser, which is this hash  { :password => ["Invalid username or password"] } .

update: The ajax call was made automatically by rails, when I add :remote => true to the form, it adds data-remote="true" attribute to the form. So instead of a manual ajax call, it was done through rails. Here is the doc explanation http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

update: I added the following code to my session_controller:
`p "I'm receiving Ajax request" if request.xhr?`
My server log confirms that it's actually receiving an ajax request; so now most likely the problem lies within why jQuery cannot detect these event triggers.

So I'm assuming the ajax events are actually triggered; the problem is, I cannot detect any of these events in my jquery code; therefore I cannot manipulate the response from the server, I cannot bind these events to any further action I want to perform. In the following code, I have confirmed the existence of the ('login_form') DOM node and the code is actually running.

Where is the hiccup? Why can't my jquery code detect ajax events?

I would really appreciate help on this issue!!

In my jquery code, I have the following; none of the callback function have been fired when I click on the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("document is ready for use");
  console.log($('.login_form'));

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:before", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:before is fired");
  });

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:beforeSend", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:beforeSend is fired");
  });

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:send", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:send is fired");
  });

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:success is fired");
  });

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:error", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:error is fired");
  });

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:complete", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:complete is fired");
  });

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:aborted:required", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:aborted:required is fired");
  });

  $(".login_form").on("ajax:aborted:file", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("ajax:aborted:file is fired");
  });


 $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $("#replaced").hide();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $("#replaced").hide();
 });


  $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function() {
    console.log("ajaxSend is fired");
  }).bind("ajaxComplete", function() {
    console.log(".ajaxComplete is fired");
  }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
    console.log(".ajaxError is fired");
  }).bind("ajaxStart", function() {
    console.log(".ajaxStart is fired");
  }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
    console.log(".ajaxStop is fired");
  }).bind("ajaxSuccess", function() {
    console.log(".ajaxSuccess is fired");
  });
});
```

First, the event is happening on a form_for DOM node. Please see below for the form code:

```
<%= form_for(:session, :url => login_path, :method => :post, :remote => true, :html => { :class => "login_form" }) do |f| %>
  <table class="sign_in_table", cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><span class="login_table_content">Email</span></td> 
      <td><%= f.text_field(:email, :placeholder => "Email", :class => "input_box_normal")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><span class="login_table_content">Password</span></td>
      <td><%= f.password_field(:password, :placeholder => "Password", :class => "input_box_normal")%></td>
    </tr>
  </table><br>
    <%= f.submit "Login", :class => "button_normal" %>
<% end %>
```

Please see below for the session controller code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(session_params[:email])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])
        login!(@user)
        format.html { redirect_to users_path }
      else
        @error_messages = { :password => ["Invalid username or password"] }
        format.json { render :json => @error_messages, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is the ajax call in your jquery code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain fully; the ajax call was made automatically by rails, when I add :remote => true to the form. So instead of a manual ajax call, it was done through rails. Here is the doc explanation http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: what file is the javascript in? create.js? application.js?

Comment: the js code is contained in it's own file, let's call it modal_ajax.js

but I believe eventually everything gets complied into application.js, so I'm not sure if it makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

This problem have been resolved.

The bug is actually in my application.html.erb file.

I accidentally added this line to my head tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This line would get jquery source code from outside instead of from within rails, therefore it must have overwritten some default rails ajax behavior. After deleting this line, I was able to detect my ajax actions with jquery!